# Read XML file and create Tree View Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, treeview

I want to create tree view structure from XML data. Can any one please help me how do I achieve this using XSLT.

### XML File:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="filename.xsl"?>
<node text="Path1">
  <node text="Folder1">
    <node text="File1.java" />
    <node text="File2.java" />
    <node text="Folder2">
        <node text="File3.java" />
        <node text="File4.java" />
    </node>
  </node>
  <node text="Folder3" > </node>
</node>
```

### Output:

```
Path1
  |-Folder1
      |-File1.java
      |-File2.java
      |-Folder2
         |-File3.java
         |-File4.java
  |-Folder3
      |-File5.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for browser view as list you can use this code

**XSLT**

```
    <xsl:template match="node">
    <ul>
        <li><xsl:value-of select="@text"/></li>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::node">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>                
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```html
<ul>
   <li>Path1</li>
   <ul>
      <li>Folder1
        <ul>
            <li>File1.java</li>
         </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>File2.java</li>
         </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Folder2</li>
            <ul>
               <li>File3.java</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
               <li>File4.java</li>
            </ul>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      <li>Folder3 </li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rupesh. It's working like charm. I received one more requirement i.e., making the tree view Expand and Collapse onClick. Any idea?

Comment: For expand and collapse you should use javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">
            <xsl:text>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Rupesh for quick response. It's displaying in single line instead of Tree View format. Any clue? My ultimate goal is to display the tree view in the browser. Can you use <ui> and <li> tags to achieve this?

Comment: I am ok to alter my xml file to achieve Tree View kind of output.